# Can I use my 2 domain controllers also as my 2 node file server cluster?

Tags: windows, domain-controller, cluster, file-sharing

I already have 2 domain controllers running Windows Server 2012 R2.   This network doesn't have any file servers or SANs.  It hardly needs any.  But, I have one small need for a shared file folder and I would prefer it to be redundant.  So I could set up 2 dedicated servers just for this purpose, but that seems like such a waste for one file folder share that will have just a couple files.  Instead, can I just use my 2 domain controllers?  I would want to install a failover cluster for file sharing on them.

Comment: Look into using DFS for this. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281957.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If number of files is so small that you don't need dedicated server, they you could just set a backup schedule to back files hourly/daily on the other server. In fact according to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2795523) it is not recommended.

Comment: Even though the # of files is small, they still have importance and need to be in sync in realtime because they are constantly updated and any reads need to be current.   So your backup workaround is not an option for me.   My question remains...   Do you know if I can create a file share failover cluster on the 2 domain controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can, sure.

Should Depends on how critical the domain is. If a large number of users depend on this domain to log into Windows then don't do it.

You'll be opening security vulnerability, introducing file system locks that will reduce stability, adding overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple question, but the answer isn't quite so simple, mostly based on what you *should* be doing, as opposed to what you *can* do.

The first issue I see is that you shouldn't use DCs as file servers, never mind fail-over clustered file servers. Domain Controllers should be treated with kid gloves and left alone to do their thing. Installing other services on them will, in the long term, cause you much grief.

As @joeqwerty has said in his comments, you might not even need a fail-over cluster. A combination of DFS-N and DFS-R can give you want you need (files stored on two or more locations accessed via a unique path), with individual servers. It's much simpler to setup and doesn't require any fancy hardware.

If you really want to setup a Windows fail-over cluster, you **need** shared storage. This isn't an option and could entail lots of extra work and money.

Finally, and this one is totally about what your business needs are, do you *need* these files to be highly available in the "multiple servers/replication/etc.." sense? In my experience most servers you buy from The Big 3 are very reliable and don't fail very often. Yes, they *will* eventually fail, but a good warranty from one of the major vendors can have you up and running (from a hardware perspective) within 3-4 hours. In short, is it really worth going through all this effort for `one file folder share that will have just a couple files`?

Comment: You're right about DFS-N and DFS-R but one use of the file share would be as a witness for a SQL AlwaysOn cluster and I think the witness may need a real file share failover cluster instead of a DFS replicated name.  I am not sure, though.

Comment: I don't see why the witness would care where/how the share is provided, so long as it works as a share. However, I've never tried it so it's possible you're right.